# sqlite - replacing existing rows in particular range with data from another table

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have  table with 1500 rows and nearly 10 columns ..

I have imported new data from csv file into another new table, now I want to copy data from this new table to already existing table's 10th column ..

when I try

```
insert into presentDB (column10) select column1 from importDB
```

its inserting another 1500 new rows ..

```
UPDATE presentDB SET column10 = importDB.column1
```

this thing is throwing an error ..

```
UPDATE presentDB SET column10 = (SELECT column1 FROM importDB WHERE rowid between 1 and 1500)
```

gets executed, but copies the first value in column1.importDB to all the cells in present db.

also what will be the query for

`copying data in particular range like 100 to 200 from importDB to 500 to 600 in presentDB`

can anyone please show a proper direction :)  thanks, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some column that identifies records.
If you have that, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE presentTab
SET column10 = (SELECT column1
                FROM importTab
                WHERE importTab.ID = presentTab.ID)
```